# Why is my method executed twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.category').click(function(){
        $("#category-menu").modal();
        $("#category-menu").css({'display' : 'block'});
        $('.single-category').click(function(){
            $('.category-link').fadeOut('slow', 'linear', fadeInCategory( $(this) ) ); 
   /*the line above some how gets called again*/
        });

    });

    $('.mp-back').click(function(){
        $('.category-link').css('display', 'none');
        var testing = $(this).closest('.mp-level');
        testing.css('display', 'none');   /*after this line */
    });

});

function fadeInCategory(category){
    category.find('.mp-level').fadeIn('slow');
    category.find('ul').fadeIn('slow');
}
function back2allCategories(){
    $('.category-link').css('display', 'block');
}
```

When `$('.single-category')` is clicked I fade out a bunch of html and fade in just this child.
`mp-back` is supposed to move back so I am fading out (or setting `display:none` as a property)

However once `$('.mp-back').click(function(){` has finished executing, this line:

```
$('.category-link').fadeOut('slow', 'linear', fadeInCategory( $(this) ) );
```

Somehow it is executed again and I can't figure out why.
(I know this is happening through break points in google chrome console)

However I can not really figure out why.

Why does this `$('.category-link').fadeOut('slow', 'linear', fadeInCategory( $(this) ) );` get re-called?

Comment: You should almost never call a function that binds an event handler inside another event handler function. Every time you click on `.category` you bind an additional click handler for `.single-category`, so you end up with multiple handlers on them.

Comment: hmm .. that makes sense ... is that the problem thouugh or just good practice?

Comment: @brendosthoughts: `is that the problem thouugh or just good practice?` What do you think? If each click adds a new event on top of the already existing one (causing multiple events being attached) , would you consider that a potential problem or *just* bad practice?

Comment: it's a potential problem for sure... in this case it is not the actual porblem though .. the actual problem in this case is `.mp-back` is a child of `.category-link` something that is not known from what I posted ... not arguing that the event handler re-asigning themselves would be a problem down the road

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every single time you click on `.category`, you are assigning a new handler to `.category-link`. Keep doing that enough times and you'll crash the browser.

There are very, very few occasions where one event handler should assign another. This is not one of them ;)

Comment: Thanks ... this makes sense ... not the solution to the problem I was having ... one handler is child of another hence why i was seeing the loop in debuger ... but this is something I was not awre of and clearly/logically could be a large problem... my code no longer looks like posted.. and hopefully mistake ill never make again

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Niets answer, you could use unbind your click event to fix the issue e.g.

```
$('.category').click(function(){
   $("#category-menu").modal();
   $("#category-menu").css({'display' : 'block'});
   // unbind the click before binding it again
   $('.single-category').unbind('click').click(function(){
       $('.category-link').fadeOut('slow', 'linear', fadeInCategory( $(this) ) ); 
        /*the line above some how gets called again*/
    });
});
```

Obviously that's a workaround and I'm not suggesting to do it, it's just something that works :)